# Cant install pandas_datareader.data

Tags: python, dataframe

'
I am trying to install 'pandas datareader data' as web

but getting this error[image]

Comment: Installing and importing are different things. Have you _installed_ `pandas_datareader`, e.g. via `pip` or `conda` or `Poetry`?

Comment: I have conda installed

Comment: That's not what I asked. Did you install _`pandas_datareader`_ into your environment?

Comment: (For example, by running `conda install pandas-datareader`)

Comment: I have ran it yet - sorry. Also do i run in CMD or conda prompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Installing and importing are different things](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18884331/354577).

Before you can `import pandas_datareader` you must install it, e.g. by running

```
conda install pandas_datareader
```

in your shell (it sounds like you use cmd.exe). Alternatively, you can do this right from Jupyter by [prefixing the command with a `!`:](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/python-ipython-diff.html#shell-assignment)

```
!conda install pandas_datareader
```

Once *installation* has finished, you should be able to `import` and use the library.